# how to create fontawesome spinner

Tags: spinner, font-awesome

I'm trying to create a spinner like [this](https://php.quicoto.com/examples/23/) (the right one).

I literally copied the code, but the result is so different (shape, speed, fluentness...)

Obviously, something is wrong. Any help?

```css
@keyframes rotation {
   0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
   }
   100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
   0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
   }
   100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes rotation {
   0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
   }
   100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
  }

.spinner{
 position:fixed;
 left:calc(50% - 15px);
 top:63px;
}

.fa-spinner{
   font-size: 5em;
   animation: rotation 2s infinite steps(8);
   -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite steps(8);
   -moz-animation: rotation 2s infinite steps(8);
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-spinner spinner"></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you cited used fontAwesome4 whereas your implementation uses FA5. I'm afraid I can't fully explain why that explains the difference (and why it was decided to do that differently), but the nice size-change during animation can only be achieved with V4, I think:

**FontAwesome 4.7**:

```css
@keyframes rotation {
   0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
   }
   100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
   0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
   }
   100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes rotation {
   0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
   }
   100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
  }

.spinner{
 position:fixed;
 left:calc(50% - 15px);
 top:63px;
}

.fa-spinner{
   font-size: 5em;
   animation: rotation 2s infinite steps(8);
   -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite steps(8);
   -moz-animation: rotation 2s infinite steps(8);
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-3x"></i>
```

**FontAwesome 5.3.1**:

```css
@keyframes rotation {
   0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
   }
   100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
   0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
   }
   100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes rotation {
   0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
   }
   100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
  }

.spinner{
 position:fixed;
 left:calc(50% - 15px);
 top:63px;
}

.fa-spinner{
   font-size: 5em;
   animation: rotation 2s infinite steps(8);
   -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite steps(8);
   -moz-animation: rotation 2s infinite steps(8);
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-3x"></i>  <!-- NB: "fas", not "fa" -->
```